# Auto-increment counter in Dynamo DB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement the auto -increment counter for hash key in dynamo db and my code fails for concurrent transactions. any help to implement the feature will be appreciated. I am new to stack over flow might be not able to specify it correctly. Any implementation will be helpful.

Answer (score 17):

You have two options, using dynamo db atomic counters or using optimistic locking at the time of incrementing the counter.

Documentation for atomic counters:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters

Documentation for optimistic locking:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html

Answer (score 7):

You can also use conditional writes to check the currently stored counter value against the value you are about to write e.g check if current count is N-1 the new value N.

I prefer this approach as it pushes the logic of incrementing the counter to your app, but the final check on correct persistence is with DynamoDB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate

Answer (score 2):

Like other SOers rightly pointed out, you can either use [AtomicCounters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) or [ConditionalUpdate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate). NOV 2018 onwards you have [Transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/) from DynamoDB (Disclaimer: Havent tested transactions personally, not sure it applies for the auto-increment usecase)

This is a quote from the official doc on **AtomicCounter**

> you can use the UpdateItem operation to implement
>   an atomic counter—a numeric attribute that is incremented,
>   unconditionally, without interfering with other write requests. (All
>   write requests are applied in the order in which they were received.)
>   With an atomic counter, the updates are not idempotent. In other
>   words, the numeric value increments each time you call UpdateItem.
>
> You might use an atomic counter to track the number of visitors to a
>   website. In this case, your application would increment a numeric
>   value, regardless of its current value. If an UpdateItem operation
>   fails, the application could simply retry the operation. This would
>   risk updating the counter twice, but you could probably tolerate a
>   slight overcounting or undercounting of website visitors.

**Transactions**

> Two new DynamoDB operations have been introduced for handling
>   transactions:
>
> TransactWriteItems, a batch operation that contains a write set, with
>   one or more PutItem, UpdateItem, and DeleteItem operations.
>   TransactWriteItems can optionally check for prerequisite conditions
>   that must be satisfied before making updates. These conditions may
>   involve the same or different items than those in the write set. If
>   any condition is not met, the transaction is rejected.
>
> TransactGetItems, a batch operation that contains a read set, with one
>   or more GetItem operations. If a TransactGetItems request is issued on
>   an item that is part of an active write transaction, the read
>   transaction is canceled. To get the previously committed value, you
>   can use a standard read.

Comment: Can you use an Atomic Counter - UpdateItem within a transaction? So that if something else in the transaction fails, it ll decrement the atomic counter value as well?